# Database-Scheme to realise university group learning

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Im pretty new to databases, so i'd really appreciate any help on this.

So what im trying to do here, i would like to create a database-scheme that helps students organize learning groups.

Students should be able to check if a group already exists, if not create it and give general description about topics, location, time, maybe add book resources etc.

Students wanting to join groups, should be able to search for subject areas & specific subjects, see how many people are already in the group and join it if fits them.

Would those tables be enough for what im trying to achieve:

users = UID(primary & unique), Name, Semester, Subject, Subject Area

groups = GID(primary), Name, Subject, Subject Area, Description, Resources, 
         NumberOfUsers

membership = UID(fk to users.UID), GID(fk to groups.GID)

Also, how can i keep groups.NumberOfUsers dynamic to change depending on how many users have a membership with that certain group?

Is there a way to limit the amount of users a group can have?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are mostly right, I have compiled some database schemas that could help you.

Table: Groups

- ID (PK| AI)
- Name (Varchar)
- Description (TEXT)
- created_by (INT | FK)
- Other informations...

There should be a pivot table for users that are in particular groups, let's name it,
Table: user_groups

- ID (PK| AI)
- group_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)

For groups resources (like books resources, videos etc.) you can create another pivot table, like following:
Table: groups_resources

- ID (PK|AI)
- group_id (FK)
- type (INT) // (optional, if you want to sort the uploaded files type)Status: 1 - book, 2 - video etc.
- path (local or external)

For your NumberOfUsers question, I would recommend not saving, as you could take that information with a simple query and not "tire" your database with that information.
However, if you still want to save that, you can simply update your table, foreach insert into user_groups.. you sql query would be:

```
Update groups SET numberofusers = numberofuser + 1 WHERE id = ?;
```

P.S. - In groups, you could use created_by OR even declare a new column (administrator_id) and assign the administrator of that group, which would have editing access (as you would plan it in your scripts).

Comment: For a many:many mapping table, such as `users_groups`, get rid of the `ID` and follow the rest of the advice [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).